# How do I limit the result data by using limit in criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria

How do I add 'limit value' in Hibernate criteria.

My code is like this

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Sample.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("colOne", colOne));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("colThree", colThree));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("colFour"));
```

How do i retrieve a single row instead of a list?

Comment: use `setMaxResults()` (or `uniqueResult()`)

Comment: uniqueResult throws an error as the result is a list and not unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get first element form your list and do cast with your class.

```
Sample sample= (Sample)ctriteria.list().get(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setMaxResults`:

```
public Criteria setMaxResults(int maxResults)
```